# Reading environment variables of openshift in angular2 based application

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, openshift

My angular 2 based application is packaged with webpack and deployed in openshift 3.
I have a requirement where to set some environment variables in openshift and control the behavior of angular2 application based on the env variable.

The variable is not going to change dynamically . If its changed , the server can be restarted . 
Is it possible to achieve it .Reading openshift environment variables in webpack ?

Comment: You can set environment variables using ``oc set env`` command. You would use normal means to read environment variables that would use for programming language you are using in server side application code. What have you tried so far? Have you looked at ``oc set env`` command at all? You can also set environment variables from web console under environment tab of a deployment configuration.

Comment: if its a server side app , its fine...i can set using oc set env and can read it easily..
Angular 2 is basically client side app packed using webpack..  its a sifferent scenario...

Comment: Your server side app would need to communicate any configuration to customise the client side browser based app somehow. OpenShift itself is not going to help on that aspect of it.

Comment: Do anyone find the solution for it.. We have the same requirement of reading environmental variable inside angular application to set some url's dynamically